# Bootstrap 2.3.2 mobile 100% width background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a problem with mobile resolutions, because background is not 100% width when I use smaller reolutions. It looks like this:

[image]

When I use higher resolutions, it works fine. I have tested my website by using http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ and it shows that 100% width background works only from 768 x 1024 (iPad - Portrait).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this lines from `bootstrap.responsive.css` file then body will be 100% fill

```
body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Or alternatively, you can also change this to

```
body {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
```

Try either of the two, that'll work for you

Comment: I'd rather go with the other answer, it's not a good idea to edit directly the bootstrap file. You should create a new file overriding bootstrap properties, because that way, you will not lost these modifications when upgrading to a new version of BOotstrap, linking a CDN, or any other reason. My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
body {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

}

or

```
body {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

or

```
body {
    background-color: yourcolor;
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems to me that padding solution doesn't work very well. If I set padding-left/right to 0, I get this:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/iFNap.png

Also, all elements in my containers don't have padding, and look so bad. I can't use background-color for body, because my footer has other color than content section etc. Any ideas how to handle with it? Btw, thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem with a page, and just adding that padding-left:0px; and padding-left:0px; to the body tag in my css did the trick perfectly without fuxing up any of my other shiz. thanks a lot, its a simple fix, but sometimes simple things like that dont mesh well with bootstrap so its nice just to find the right one. :)